# Verify a signature JWT.IO in Kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, jwt

i would need to validate a token with jwt.io

To do this I have a token (license)
"eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ0ZW5hbnRJZCI6MjcwMzYwLCJwYWNrYWdlc.........."

and a json (certificate)

"keys": [
{
"kid": "1",
"e": "AQAB",
"kty": "RSA",
"alg": "RS256",
"n": "rXYc2Ehtb42R83kLIw56biI/ABOp03lzbYHdXI0caeli.......",
"use": "sig"
}

inside the debugger of the jwt.io site with this information I receive that the "signature is verified".

I'm looking for some scripts on the net that can allow me to do the same thing

Same on the jwt.io site I find that I can use the code reported here https://github.com/PhilJay/JWT which, however, if I understand correctly, does not use the RS256 algorithm but ES256 and therefore should not work.

I'm trying the same but honestly I don't understand what the decoder is asking for in the example

val valid = JWT.verify (tokenString, jwk, decoder)
the first two I believe are the data I have.

can you give me some suggestions or give me some other code to verify the signature?

Comment: You can also use libraries in other JVM languages from kotlin (in your case)

Comment: Hi @user28434 I changed library but I always get the message that the token is not valid, can you give me some advice? This is my code https://pl.kotl.in/pppGwNKa0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here

val nInt = Biginteger(1, Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(n))

You have to take only the element n of cert and not all cert(json)

```
        val e = obj_cert.asJsonObject["e"].asString
        val n = obj_cert.asJsonObject["n"].asString.replace('+', '-').replace('/', '_').replace("=", "")
        val eInt = BigInteger(1, Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(e))
        val nInt = BigInteger(1, Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(n))

        val spec = RSAPublicKeySpec(nInt, eInt)
        val publicKey =    KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePublic(spec) as RSAPublicKey

        val algorithm: Algorithm = Algorithm.RSA256(publicKey, null)
        val verifier: JWTVerifier = com.auth0.jwt.JWT.require(algorithm).build()

        verifier.verify(license)
```